# Idempotent Semigroup $S$ with Equivalence Relation $(a R b) \iff (aba=a), (bab=b)$: $S/R$ is commutative - why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, idempotents

This is exercise 11.19 (h) in Seth Warner's "Modern Algebra".

We are given that $S$ is an idempotent semigroup, that is: $\forall a \in S: aa = a$.

Let $R$ be the equivalence relation defined as:
$$aRb \iff (aba=a) \land (bab=b)$$

We have that $R$ is a congruence relation on $S$, that is:
$$aRb \land cRd \iff (ac) R (bd)$$

We have to prove that the quotient structure $S/R$ is a *commutative* idempotent semigroup.

Proving idempotence is trivial, as $[a]_R  [a]_R = [aa]_R = [a]_R$.

But I can't work out where to start on commutativity.

I see $[a]_R [b]_R = [axabyb]_R$ where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary such that $x R a$ and $y R b$ but I can't drive off from there.

During the course of the exposition to demonstrate that $R$ is a congruence relation, which is part (g) of this question, various properties about $S$ and $R$ are demonstrated, all building from things like "if $xy = y$ and $yx = x$ then $\forall z: zxzy=zy$ and $zyzx=zx$" but I can't see how to use that approach here. $axabyb$ is general, and there is no suggestion that any of those properties apply there.

For context, I am self-taught and I am doggedly plugging away at this work question by question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $ab \mathrel{R} ba$, that is, according to the definition of $R$, $(ab)(ba)(ab) = ab$ and $(ba)(ab)(ba) = ba$. But since $S$ is idempotent, one has
$$(ab)(ba)(ab) = ab^2a^2b = abab = (ab)^2 =ab.$$
The second equality is dual (just exchange $a$ and $b$).

Comment: Having thought about this, I need to ask: *why* does it suffice to prove $ab \ R \ ba$? That is, why is it that if $ab \ R \ ba$ then $[a]_R [b]_R = [b]_R [a]_R$? It must be obvious but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I took for granted that you already proved that $R$ is a congruence (a non-trivial result). Then $[a]_R[b]_R = [ab]_R$ and $[ba]_R = [b]_R[a]_R$. But since $ab \mathrel{R} ba$, $[ab]_R = [ba]_R$.

Comment: Thank you, yes of course it *was* obvious.